# if $\Delta u = |\nabla u|^{3/2}$ then $u \in C^{\infty}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, laplacian, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose $u \in H^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R^2})$. I want to show that if $\Delta u  = |\nabla u|^{3/2}$ in the distributional sense then $u \in C^{\infty}$.

I know that since $\nabla u \in L^2$ (I'll omit the $_{\text{loc}}$ subscripts) then $|\nabla u|^{3/2} \in L^{4/3}$ hence by standard regularity results for the Laplacian we get $u \in W^{2,4/3}$ then Sobolev embedding gives $u \in W^{1,4}$, so $|\nabla u |^{3/2} \in L^{8/3}$ hence (Laplacian regularity) $u \in W^{2,8/3}$ and so $u \in C^1$.

If $u \in C^1$ then $|\nabla u|^{4/3}$ is continuous, so $u \in C^2$, then $|\nabla u|^{4/3}$ is $C^1$ and $u$ is $C^3$, but I don't know how to go further. $|x|^{4/3}$ is a $C^1$ function, but not more than that so I don't know how to continue my bootstrapping. If the right hand side was some smooth function of $\nabla u$ then it would be fairly simple, but it's not the case here - I'd be grateful for suggestions on how to deal with that.

Comment: Here is an idea: your problem is in the points where $\nabla u=0$, however, in these points, you must have $\Delta u=0$, hence, your function is harmonic in these points. We know that harmonicity implies regularity, however, this is done when $u$ is harmonic in some open domain. Maybe you can adapt the proof for the case of a point?